# My code seems to only let player 2 win. I am not sure what I need to change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one human player and one random player. 
The human player is an input and the random player just plays a random move. I play them against each other and player 2 always wins.

I am not sure what is missing. I have tried multiple things. I have tried editing the beats function but I need that for the homework. They gave us that in the starter code.

I am thinking it has something to do with the players.

This is a link to the code: https://codeshare.io/aY9KPM

Comment: Please include your code (or a [mcve]) in the question itself. Stack Overflow questions need to be more or less self contained. If the linked code changes or gets taken down in the future, this question as it stands will be incomprehensible.

Comment: Please include the essential parts of your code into the question; it should be a [mre] to ilustrate the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. [Brandon Wang has identified one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876460/1405065), that you've forgotten to call `beats` in an `elif` block of your `play_round` method. But that should just cause the human to win all ties, not absolutely all games. The reason that player 1 can't ever win is that the human's input is always being ignored.

The cause of that is in this section of the `HumanPlayer` class:

```
    while True:
        if playermove.lower() not in moves:
            print("Sorry invalid imput")
            playermove = input("Please Pick: Rock, Paper, or Scissors ")
        else:
            break
            return (playermove)
```

Specifically, the issue is that you `break` out of the loop before the `return` statement can return the human player's chosen move. The `return` statement never gets run, and so the function ends up returning `None` by default (since its code runs off the end of the function without returning anything else).

You can fix this issue by simply removing the `break` statement. The loop will end anyway when the `return` statement exits the function, so there's no need to `break` separately.

Or you could put the condition of the test (an unknown move) in the `while` loop, rather than in a separate `if` statement inside, and `return` after the loop ends:

```
playermove = input("Please Pick: Rock, Paper, or Scissors ").lower()
while playermove not in moves:
    print("Sorry invalid imput")
    playermove = input("Please Pick: Rock, Paper, or Scissors ").lower()
return playermove
```

Note that in Python 3.8 (which is in beta right now, not yet fully released), you will be able to avoid the duplication of the `input` line using the new `:=` walrus operator that does mid-expression assignments:

```
while (playermove := input("Please Pick: Rock, Paper, or Scissors ").lower()) not in moves:
    print("Sorry invalid imput")
```

Note that I changed the `lower` call to be done immediately after getting the input. In addition to looking nicer, this actually fixes another bug you'd find eventually, where miscapitalized move names would be recognized by the input code as valid, but would get returned to the game code in their unexpected format, which would cause the other code to subtly break.

You might also want to tighten up the other parts of your logic to better handle invalid strings. If your `beats` function did some validation, for instance, you'd have figured out that a `None` was getting passed around, rather than just getting an unexpected winner.

Comment: Thanks so much! the project is working as intended now. I am just beginning I hope soon this stuff becomes 2nd nature

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo on line 81: `elif (move2, move1):` This `elif` will always return true. I'm assuming you forgot to call the beats function. Change it to `elif beats(move2, move1):`